# Let $ X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ compact and $ f:X \to \mathbb{R} $ is a function

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functions

Let $ X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be compact and $ f:X \to \mathbb{R} $ be a function such that for all $ t \in \mathbb{R} $, the set $ f^{-1} [t, \infty) $ is  closed. Which one of the following statement is correct and why the rest are incorrect?

1) There exists a $ x_0 \in X $ such that $$ f(x_0)= \sup_{x\in X} f(x)<\infty.$$

2) $ f$ is bounded.

3) There exists $ y_0 \in X $ such that $$ f(y_0)= \inf_{x\in X} f(x)> -\infty.$$
4) $f$ can be unbounded.

Comment: Initially you have written $f$ is a vector-valued function. But the rest of the question assume $f$ is a real-valued function. Please correct it.

Comment: Look at the function $f(x) = |x|$.

Comment: Try using the Cantor Intersection theorem to prove (2)

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice theorem that will help you here: Suppose $X$ is compact, and let $V_0 \supset V_1 \supset V_2 \supset \cdots$ be a decreasing collection of closed subsets such that $\cap_i V_i = \emptyset$. Then there exists some $k$ such that $V_k = \emptyset$. Now lets prove some stuff.

**I: $f$ is bounded above.** Let $V_n = f^{-1}([n,\infty))$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $V_n$ is closed and we have $V_0 \supset V_1 \supset V_2 \supset \cdots$, and $\cap_iV_i = \emptyset$. So using the above theorem, there is some $k$ such that $V_k = \emptyset$. Hence $f^{-1}([k,\infty)) = \emptyset$, and so $k$ is an upper bound for $f$.

**II: $f$ achieves its upper bound.** By $I$, $f$ is bounded above. Let $M = \sup \, f(x)$. Let $V_n = f^{-1}([M - 1/n,\infty))$. Then $V_1 \supset V_2 \supset \cdots$ are closed. But we cannot have $V_k = \emptyset$ for any $k$, otherwise $M$ would not be the least upper bound. By the converse of the above theorem, $\cap_i V_i \neq \emptyset$. Then pick $x_0 \in \cap_i V_i$, we must have $f(x_0) = M$.

**III: $f$ need not be bounded below.** For instance, define $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) = -1/x$ for all $x \neq 0$.

This should answer all your questions I think.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Since $A_t:= f^{-1}[t,\infty)$ is closed in $X$ then $A_t$ is
compact.

Assume that if $x_n\in A_t,\ f(x_n)\rightarrow \infty$, then since
  $A_t$ is compact so there exists convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$.
  And in further its limit $x_\infty $ is in $A_t$. Let
  $$f(x_\infty)=x_0\in [t,\infty)$$

Consider $A_{t+1}$ which does not contain $x_\infty$. So it is a
contradiction. Hence $A_t$ does not contain a sequence $x_n$ s.t.
$f(x_n)\rightarrow \infty$. So 1) is true. $4)$ is not true.

(2) $X=[0,1],\ n=1,\ f(0)=0,\ f(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$ Hence $2),\ 3)$ is
not true.